# Is there any Cocos2d based open-source iPhone game exist?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I want to study Cocos2d, seems it's a good framework for iPhone game programming. So is there any Cocos2d based open-source iPhone game exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place to ask this is on [cocos2d google group](http://groups.google.com/group/cocos2d-iphone-discuss?pli=1).

I believe there are several games and game demos available to study. The developer is pretty active with the framework although he is currently on vacation for the holidays.

Answer (score 2):

Tweejump
http://tweejump.com/
http://github.com/haqu/tweejump/tree/master

ABC123
http://kwigbo.com/wp/2009/05/02/abc123-iphone-cocos2d-game-open-source/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of a ton of examples, all Cocos2d based:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/24798

direct link to downloads page:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ap9yzw5RaZIZdFNoWEtvTXdfbThHM0hJUGxWUHZwSGc#gid=0

Note: Click on the "DropBox" links to get the source without having to go through lots of clicks at some other site.